# How can I insert both ID of Two tables (Many to Many Relationship)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have three table Category and Company and Company_category.

Company model

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Category::class);
}
```

Category model

```
public function companies(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class,'company_category');
}
```

When I try Insert Company ID into table

CategoryController Code:

```
$category = new Category();
$category->companies()->sync($request->get('company_id'));
```

How can I insert category_id with company_id both at once 
only this code return error :

**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'category_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `company_category` (`category_id`, `company_id`) values (, 1))**

Comment: Save `$category` first, so it has an ID

Comment: in the migration table of category table make category_id->nullable() try that

Comment: @haffisasma I don't want that category_id  be null

Comment: put how you make your foriegn key please

Comment: $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');

$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');

Comment: @Stormhammer Thanks <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Stormhammer mentioned, you need to save the category first or else it does not have an id.

```
$category = new Category();
$category->save();
$category->companies()->sync($request->get('company_id'));
```